# ADXL 345 interfacing with either ATmega32 A or arduino

Tags: arduino

well i'm working on ADXL345 and tried using ATmega32A as master. It din't turned out and i shifted to Arduino-uno. After connecting properly using I2C, i am getting 0 as acceleration values in all the 3 axis. I have tried the code mentioned in the main arduino forum. It worked for many others as of the posts are concerned. can anyone help me in this context?

Comment: How many of the accelerometer chips do you have - maybe it's been destroyed?

Comment: What code are you using? Please add it to your question. Also try to rephrase your question; it's difficult to follow what you're trying, what went wrong.